# PostgreSQL or SQL in general: LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE condition behave unexpectedly (for me?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

Let's say I have two tables, which may or may not have a relation. For example, books and tags. So, let's say I want to select books, that don't have tag "Sci-Fi", I would write something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  books
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  tags ON books.id = tags.taggable_id
WHERE
  tags.name NOT IN ('Sci-Fi')
```

I wasn't expecting that this will also exclude books with no tags at all.
I tried this:

```
WHERE
  tags.name IN (NULL, 'Novel'...)
```

And ended up with this, which I'm pretty sure not the best way to do this:

```
WHERE
  tags.name NOT IN ('Sci-Fi') OR tags.id IS NULL
```

The question is why and is there another way?

P.S. don't ask about why tags are created this way, it's just for the sake of example and that's the best analogy I managed to squeeze out of myself :)

Comment: Just a remark: This doesn't select "books that don't have tag 'Sci-Fi'", but all books with all tags other than 'Sci-Fi'. To do the former you would use `NOT EXISTS` rather than joining the tables.

Comment: Saying 'I want to select books, that don't have tag "Sci-Fi"' I meant I'm interested in books with no tags at all too. Two answers suggest moving condition tags.name NOT IN ('Sci-Fi') to JOIN clause but as far as i can tell this just makes tags fields null but still selects books that have Sci-Fi tag.

Comment: No, what I am saying is: You are not selecting *books*, you are selecting *book-tag combinations*.

Comment: Oh, okay, then :) I would have considered this, but I need 'join-way' because I'm using rails and looking for a way to do this with AR and not pure sql :)

Comment: Do you want books without a certain single tag, or might you ever want books without any of a larger set of tags? Because the clearest way to do this for just one value in the list doesn't involve `NOT IN`. (It seems like you might be using `NOT IN` only because you think it works when `<>` doesn't.) What columns do you want in the result?

Answer (score 5):

All conditions in the `where` clause filter the resulting data. So put the `Sci-Fi` condition on the `join` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM books
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON books.id = tags.taggable_id
                    AND tags.name NOT IN ('Sci-Fi')
WHERE tags.id IS NULL
```

To get books that can have more than one tag and should not have the Sci-Fi tag at all then you can do

```
SELECT books.id, books.name
FROM books
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON books.id = tags.taggable_id
GROUP BY books.id, books.name
HAVING sum(case when tags.name = 'Sci-Fi' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: This just doesn't join tags for books with sci-fi tag, but still selects them

Answer (score 1):

If you include a condition on the "outer" table, this effectively turns the outer join into an **inner** join.

This is because for any row that is not matched in the outer table, all columns from that table are returned as `null`. So for any non-matched row, `tags.name` will be null.

Any comparison with null yields `null` which in this case means "not true" and thus those rows are removed by the where condition - which they would have been as well with an inner join.

You need to put that condition into the `join` clause, not the `where` clause.

```
ON books.id = tags.taggable_id and tags.name NOT IN ('Sci-Fi')
```

And as you are not interested in books that do not have that tag, you can change the outer join into an inner join:

```
select *
from books
  join tags on books.id = tags.taggable_id 
           and tags.name NOT IN ('Sci-Fi')
```

Comment: This does not return books with no tags at all.